# How to access fields after cross join of the same table in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I ran a cross join on a table and it worked fine. Now the problem is I don't know how to address the same field from the resulting dataframe.

```
df = spark.sql("select p1.id, p2.id from profile p1 CROSS JOIN profile p2 WHERE p1.id < p2.id")
```

When I printed out the first row, I got something like this:

```
Row(id=21398968, id=76109821)
```

Running "print(res_2[0]['id'])" yields only the first one as a scalar value (not a list)

Comment: Does changing the query to have an `AS` clause do the trick of avoiding the name conflict? I'm not sure what's going on with `id.t1`. Should that be `p1.id`?

Comment: a good catch. let me fix the typo and also I think you are right about AS. I will try that when I am in front of my working station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query to be:

```
df = spark.sql("select p1.id AS p1_id, p2.id AS p2_id from profile CROSS JOIN profile p2 WHERE p1.id < p2.id")
```

By using `AS` you should be able to avoid the name conflict.